# Disable dates dynamically in angular date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm stuck in between disabling a date from angular js date picker

Fiddle link :[Angularjs date picker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ata3YOsl7p9hVNMRQFGT?p=preview)
I tried by giving the date that I wanted to disable into the $scope variable function like this

> > $scope.toDisable="Sun Apr 27 2014 22:14:25 +0100";

in the `date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"` function.But its not working.

Any help will really be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: how do u get the value for `$scope.toDisable` hard code ?

Comment: The value that I will be getting from backend will be of that type